# Node js chat server - user auth

Tags: node.js, authentication, chat

Im tring to make a node js chat server that will run on another server of my website server.
I want to be sure that all the users are connecting to the node js server is the users that are in my website.

How can i check it?
Thanks

Comment: [This](https://github.com/braitsch/node-login) is a great place to start. Don't just use his exact code, but look at how it's set up and you can use that to get you going and learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way you can access your website user session in Nodejs. You need to use separate session storage which can be accessed by both Webserver and NodeJS. So this will fix your user 'Authenticaion' in both servers.

I chose Redis over Memcache for custom session storage because you don't want to lose all your existing session data on server restart. If you are using PHP https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis will help you install the Redis extension. And for Nodejs you can easily search, install and configure the Redis.

Refer here for more useful info http://webandphp.com/IntegratingNode.jswithPHP